# MP3 duration not reported when delivered via PHP

Tags: php, http, stream, mp3

I’ve got some PHP code set up to send various mp3 files under certain conditions. While it works to send the audio data, the mp3 file’s duration isn’t reported (so, for example, it’s reported as a ‘live broadcast’ when viewed in Safari). Linking directly to the file works properly, so I presume the issue is to do with my PHP code and HTTP headers.

Currently, to send the file, I’m doing this:

```
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Type: audio/mpeg");
header(“Content-length: “ . filesize($filePath));
header(“Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filename”);
header(“Cache-Control: no-cache”);
readfile($filePath);
die();
```

Essentially I just want the PHP to deliver the file in exactly the same way as if I linked directly to the mp3 file itself. Any ideas on what I’m doing wrong would be appreciated!

Edit: Solved! Figured out the issue and described in the comment below.

Comment: from what i read `audio/mpeg` is used for audio broadcasting, why aren't you using `audio/mp3` ?

Comment: Fire up your browser dev tools, and go figure out what the significant differences are in the headers you are sending, and the ones the web server sends when you request the mp3 URL directly …?

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, unfortunately neither of those things worked. I eventually figured out that my code was improperly handling partial file requests, which are used on Safari/iOS streaming stuff. Implemented some code to deal with that and all is well!